# std::chrono::duration_cast count() returns zero

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++-chrono

Here is the simple program (array sorting):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

typedef unsigned int myInt;

static void shellSort(myInt arr[], const myInt length) {
    if (length < 2) {
        return;
    }
    myInt i, j, step;
    myInt tmp;
    for (step = length / 2; step > 0; step /= 2) {
        for (i = step; i < length; i++) {
            tmp = arr[i];
            for (j = i; j >= step; j -= step) {
                if (tmp < arr[j - step]) {
                    arr[j] = arr[j - step];
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    const int arrSize = 2000;
    std::array<myInt, arrSize> arr;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point timeStart, timeEnd;

    //Array filling and shuffling
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }
    std::random_shuffle(arr.begin(), arr.end());

    //Array sorting and time measurement
    timeStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    shellSort(arr._Elems, arrSize);
    timeEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    printf("%llu", std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(timeEnd - timeStart).count());
    _getch();
}
```

and it returns 0. 0 nanoseconds for sorting array of 2000 elements. Looks very strange. I noticed that it happens when function execution time is small, but 0 nanosecond - definitely a lie.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYH4U.png)

*Visual Studio 2013, Build - Release, Platform x64, Win10 x64*

Please, tell me, why this can happen?

Comment: Short solution for this sort of problems:
`FILETIME tm;
inline ULONGLONG getMicroSeconds() {
 GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(&tm);
 return (((ULONGLONG)tm.dwHighDateTime << 32) | (ULONGLONG)tm.dwLowDateTime) / 10;
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard does not require a minimum resolution for the `std::high_resolution_clock`.

> 20.11.7.3
>
> Class high_resolution_clock [time.clock.hires] Objects of class
>   high_resolution_clock represent clocks with the shortest tick period.
>   high_resolution_- clock may be a synonym for system_clock or
>   steady_clock.

Emphasis: *may be a synonym for system_clock or steady_clock*

You need to check your compiler's documentation. Your compiler's `std::high_resolution_clock`'s resolution is probably too coarse to measure such small intervals, so your measured starting and ending time is the same.

Comment: Probably useful: one simple way to find out the resolution is `std::cout << std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration::period::den << std::endl;`

Comment: Thank you! That's right.
`std::cout << std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration::period::den << std::endl;` returns 10000000

Comment: @R95 - On your system, I believe Visual Studio 2015 would have a greater resolution. More like 100 ns.